# The controller doesn't match the mesh

Tags: mesh, rigify

The controllers or my rig are created outside the mesh when I generate. Is it normal ?
[image: not match]

Comment: Did you tried to apply, location, rotation and scale on your armature before hitting generate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In object mode, Hit Ctrl + A, and select the menus one by one as shown below:

[image]

After applying please try to generate it

Comment: Thank you. I made silly question since i'm still new to blender.

Comment: No problem, I am glad it worked for you :) Thanks for accepting anwser